# Create a hyper link on Html URL with Jquery except img src link

Tags: jquery, javascript-framework

I am trying to make a hyperlink on every url in my page.
There is code like this:

```
<div id="divC">
       Hello testing message 
       My profile link : http://stackoverflow.com/users/568085/abhishek and 
       my user account link : 
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/568085/abhishek">
    <img height="58" width="208" title="Stack Overflow profile for Abhishek at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" alt="Stack Overflow profile for Abhishek at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/568085.png?theme=dark">
    </a>
</div>
```

and I used below javascript function to add link on every URL in content page :

```
<script>
   //call function for linking every url
    createLinks();
    function createLinks()
    {
        var exp=/(((\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;     
        $("div#divC").each(function(index) {            
             $(this).html($(this).html().replace(exp, "<a target='_self' class='msg_links' href=$1>$1</a>"));
        });
    }
      </script>
```

In above code working fine but I don't want to create link on **`<img src='www.test.com'>`**.
when I run this it also created link in the **`<img src="<a href='www.test.com'>www.test.com</a>" >`** , 
 **How can I avoid create link in** `<img>` src.?

Comment: You should be able to tweak your regex to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... I see what you are doing. I've did it a while ago, building a plugin that replaces smiley's :D. Does this code work better?

```
 //call function for linking every url
    createLinks();


    function createLinks()
    {
        var exp=/(((\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;     


        $("div#divC")
        .contents()
        .filter(function () {

            if (typeof (Node) == 'undefined') {
                return this.nodeType == 3;
            }
            else {
                return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
            }
        }).each(function(index) {  

            var x = $(this)[0].nodeValue;
            if (x != '') {
               x = x.replace(exp, "<a target='_self' class='msg_links' href='$1'>$1</a>");
               $(this).replaceWith(x);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: not working, b'coz When I call the java-script function there is not any element <a> into "divC" tag.. after the calling it added <a> in each URL. that's the problem.

Comment: @Abhishek thanks! It wasn't clear you only wanted to parse text. This can be very evil :P last time I wanted to make this it took me some hours to find out what I was doing wrong, but the code above always works... so spread it :D hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

Put an id to you  tag and match it with your jquery

```
 1. <a id="target" href="your/target/url">
 2. ${"#target"}.attr('href','new/target/url')
```

It is because you are using .each(). If you want to change multiple use a class attribute for your  tags.

Comment: I dont want to added ID in each <a> tag, It comes dynamic, I only except linking in <img src=''> only, other code is working fine.